# How to delete the 'last item' of a LCRS tree?

Tags: c++, data-structures, tree

I'm trying to build a left child right sibling tree, but I have a bug in my code.

The bug happens when I'm going do remove the "last item" of my tree. In the main example of this [little project](https://github.com/itepifanio/dataStructures/tree/master/Estrutura%20de%20Dados%20Basicas/estruturas/leftChildRightSibling) if I "erase" the number 9 and print() after that, then will show the number 0 instead 9, but none should be shown.

```
void remove(T value){
        auto *node = this->search_node(value);

        if(node == NULL){
            std::cout << std::endl << "The value is not in the tree" << std::endl;
        } else if(node == this->root) {
            this->root = NULL;
        } else {
            if(node->sibling == NULL && node->child == NULL) {
                // Works, but attribute "0" to the node->value when I print
                *node = NULL; 
            } else if(node->sibling == NULL && node->child != NULL){
                *node = *node->child;
            } else {
                *node = *node->sibling;
            }
        }
    }
```

I know I'm not really deleting the value which is being removed, so tips and advices to do it are welcome too.

Comment: *node = NULL seems odd.  What is the type of node?  Maybe node->parent->child = NULL to empty the point value?

Comment: I also think get the parent and put the pointer to child as null, but this kind of tree does'nt have a pointer to the parent, so I'm researching to other ways to implement

Comment: Maybe add a field the indicates a node is deleted in that case?  So the node will still be present but the search_node will check for the 'deleted' flag.

Comment: If you want to delete a node, you have to unlink it from the tree. And to unlink, you have to know the node's parent. If your `node` structure does not contain a link to its parent, then your `search_node` function will have to return the parent.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, guys. I will try the JimMischel approach, using search_node function to return the parent, but if the code gets uggly then I will use a pointer to parent as mentioned by @MatthewFisher